# Prime decomposition of pR where R=$\mathbb{A}\cap \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ with $\alpha^5=5(\alpha+1)$, exercise 27 chapter 3 of Marcus

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

I'm trying to do exercise 27 in chapter of Marcus but it seems to me there is a typo or maybe it's me not understanding.

The exercise is the following

> Let $\alpha^5=5(\alpha+1)$ R=$\mathbb{A}\cap \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$.
>
> Let **$p\neq 3$** be a prime of $\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> Show that the prime decomposition of pR can be determined by factoring $x^5-5x-5 \; mod\; p$
>
> Do it for p=2

The hint is to use a previous exercise that tells us that the discriminant of $\alpha$, root of the irreducible polynomial $x^5+ax+b$ is $disc(\alpha)=4^4a^5+5^5b^4$ so in our case the discriminant is $5^5*3^3*41$ (isn't it?).

Another theorem (27 chapter 3 of Marcus Number Fields) tells us that we can decompose pR factoring the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ if $p\not||S/R[\alpha]|$ where S is the integer ring of L and R is the integer ring of K, with L:K.

If I'm not wrong in our case we have $|S/R[\alpha]|=|\mathbb{A}\cap\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]/\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]|$.

A last corollary tells us that if $p^2\not| disc(\alpha)$ then the hypotesis of the theorem are satisfied.

This allows me to say that all the primes but maybe 3 and 5 satisfy the theorem hypotesis, however I don't know how to say that actually 5 is good but 3 is not.

My last option is to compute an integral basis but it seems a long process so I'm asking if there is another way to do it.

Comment: There is also a useful theorem: let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer, let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Assume that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $p$-Eisenstein. Then $p\nmid [O_L:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]](=\vert O_L/\mathbb{Z}[\alpha])$, where $O_L$ is the ring of integers of $L$. 

In your case, the minimal polynomial is $X^5-5X-5$, which is $5$-Eisenstein. So the decomposition of $5$ is reflected by the decomposition of $X^5-5X-5$ mod $5$.

Comment: Note that the exercise does not ask to show that it does not work for $3$. It indeed does not work: $X^5-5X-5$ has a decomposition of the form $f_1^2f_2$ mod $3$, while $3$ actually does not ramify. A way to see that whould be to compute the discriminant (which is $5^5\cdot 41$), but I don't see an easy argument to do so for the moment.

Comment: Ok, very nice. In particular the first theorem. If you write an actual answer based on that I can mark it as solving the problem (I indeed like my questions all to be marked as solved ).
 If it's not to much could you give me some hints also on the other problem I have open about pR decomposition? (it's the same topic but with a pure cubic extension)

Comment: Done. I'll think about your other problem later ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a useful theorem: let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer, let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Assume the minimial polynomial of $\alpha$ is $p$-Eisenstein. Then $p\nmid [O_L:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]$, where $O_L$ is the ring of integers of $L$.

IN your case, the minimal polynomial is $X^5-5X-5$, which is $5$-Eisenstein. So the decomposition of $5$ is reflected by the decomposition of s $X^5-5X-5\mod 5.$

Note that the exercise does not ask to show that it does not work ofr $3$. It indeed does not work: modulo $3$, $X^5-5X-5$ has a decomposition into irreducble factors of the form $f_1^2f_2$, while $3$ actually does not ramify in $L$. A way to see htat would be to compute the discriminant, which is $5^2\cdot 41$, but I on't see an easy argument to do so at this moment.